# undefined control sequence, again :/ 2.0

Tags: mathtools, undefined, latextools

I'm pretty new to LaTeX, and using an android device for it. But still, I would like the error to be pointed, I'm still a newcomer to logfiles, and they didn't get as objective with this error.

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzynD.jpg)

[Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUatk.jpg)

Comment: I've managed to take out the ones that involved /sin x and /cos x but the fraction still fails

Comment: Solved. don't know how to delete or end post. it was not the fraction and yes a double q in /leqq

Comment: You need to learn to put spaces after the macros, also after `\leq`. All the error messages I saw originated from these errors.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I see, ty

Comment: In the log file, it's always the command right before the line break that's the problem.

Comment: @Teepeemm yeah it took me a while to see that hehe ty the same, I just managed to /fbox{}, I'm happy xD

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! please (i) images in link with copy from the editor (which we can test) (ii) in question replace your links with their content (after while can happens, that links will be dead) .